# Interpretation of regression coefficient with log independent variable and percentage dependent variable

Tags: regression, econometrics, regression-coefficients, logarithm

I have a linear regression model where my dependent variable, cancellation rates is measured in terms of percentages and the independent variable, waiting times is measured in terms of logs. Suppose if the estimated beta coefficient is 0.24. Then what is the interpretation of the coefficient?

Is it 1% increase in waiting time leads to an estimated 0.24 percentage point increase in cancellation rates?

Comment: Does this Q&A help https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199256/how-to-interpret-regression-equations-with-logarithms-based-on-log-difference-b?rq=1

Comment: Log-transformed values can not be interpreted in terms of percentage change. Moreover, the linear regression should be applied when we have absolute measures of data for dependent as well as independent variables.

Comment: You may edit your question in the light of my comments if  you feel comfortable.

Comment: Thank you for all you comments and help. The link was very useful.